# Закругленные углы у картинки

Tags: css

Какой надо написать код, чтобы у картинки были не острые уголки, а круглые?

Comment: Вы все никак не успокоитесь. Используйте гугл. А так же сайт htmlbook.ru. Там есть рецепты, примеры и форум, где вы, имея немного терпения и желания научиться чему то, найдете то что вам нужно. Удачи

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос был задан более 3 лет назад и имеет решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селектор CSS [border-radius](htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius) вам поможет
P.S: [border radius generator](http://border-radius.com/)